# Change page and URL without refreshing the Page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi and I'm terribly sorry for asking such question.

I'm quite catching up on Laravel, maybe 30% smarter than before but I'm stuck on this kind of scenario.

How do I call a blade with all parameters passed to its controller without refreshing the page.

Here's my folder structure (I will not place all just controller, pages)

[Folrder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvrFx.png)

Now, I'm in let's say **dashboard.blade.php**

In the Side bar of my dashboard I want to go to a link

```
 <li class="nav-item">
   <a href="{{url('/get-greeting/{id}/{user}')}}" class="nav-link get-greeting">
      <i class="nav-icon fas fa-table"></i>
      <p>
         Requested Son
         <span class="right badge badge-danger side-span requested-span"></span>
      </p>
   </a>
</li>
```

**Route will be**

```
Route::any('/get-greeting/{id}/{user}', 'DefaultController@pullGreeting')->name('getgreeting');
```

**Controller will be**

```
public function pullGreeting($id, $user){

     $userName = User::activeUser($user);
     $defaultarray = array( 'greetingLogs' => recordLogs::pullgreetings($user) );
     return view('pages/department1/greetings',$defaultarray);

}
```

When I click it, it refreshes the page. Anyone, can you help me and pinpoint where am I doing wrong so I can make it not refreshing the page but instead changing the blade dynamically?

Does this matter?

```
return view('pages/department1/greetings',$defaultarray);
```

or

```
return view('pages.department1.greetings',$defaultarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side programming language therefore any changes to the view will require a full page refresh.

Without the use of Javascript, achieving a part page refresh would require the use of an old school technique called `Frames`.

You could redesign your application to render HTML via different endpoints and have a Javascript powered frontend that calls to those endpoints.

You could easily achieve through the use of JS Libraries such as React or JQuery.